# Why is Spark's show() function very slow?

Tags: python, apache-spark

I have

```
df.select("*").filter(df.itemid==itemid).show()
```

and that never terminated, however if I do

```
print df.select("*").filter(df.itemid==itemid)
```

It prints in less than a second. Why is this?

Comment: What is your setup? Local mode? Standalone? try something like this: `df = spark.createDataFrame([('a',), ('b',), ('c',)], ['col1'])` followed by `df.show()` (should be a matter of seconds)

Comment: @TwUxTLi51Nus I am on my local machine, connected to an Oracle database. And yes that took a second to show.

Comment: how do you invoke Spark? via the `pyspark` shell? What is your "Spark Master"? Is the Oracle Database on your local machine or remote? Can you connect to the Oracle Database using other tools than Spark

Comment: Maybe you should rephrase your question, because, the way it is stated now, it does not reflect your problem. Justin Pihony gave the correct answer to your questions as of now, this however does not solve your issue.

Comment: @TwUxTLi51Nus Sorry I am new to Spark so I'm not sure what a "Spark Master" is... I am running a Python script and running it. The database is remote and I am able to connect it with other tools. The dataframe is returned from a Spark SQL query. If I use regular SQL the query will take >20 minutes I'd say, but using Spark SQL it took around 10 seconds which I find kind of odd

Comment: In that case, as a starter, you should really familiarize yourself with the Spark basics: [Programming Guide](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html) - [Spark SQL](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html) - look for the terms "lazy evaluation", "actions", "transformations", ...

Comment: so, you start the python interpreter, import pyspark, and call `SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate`?

Comment: @TwUxTLi51Nus Yes I do that. I had no problem with show() for other sql queries, and used Spark's built in sql functions for those. For this one particularly I executed raw sql with SparkSession.sql. Research say they don't make a difference though.

Comment: I have the same problem, I am using pyspark and jupyter notebook, I access around 20M dataset, however I am surprised to see that all other functions, incuding UDFs execute much faster than show!

Answer (score 2):

That's because `select` and `filter` are just building up the execution instructions, so they aren't doing anything with the data. Then, when you call `show` it actually executes those instructions. If it isn't terminating, then I'd review the logs to see if there are any errors or connection issues. Or maybe the dataset is still too large - try only taking 5 to see if that comes back quick.

Comment: I tried `df.show(1)` but that is also taking forever. I don't think it's a connection error either

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens if you dont have enough  available memory in computer. free up some memory and try again.

Comment: I am running it on colab and databricks cluster and am getting similar issues:(